# How to get profile information of user who comment on my Instagram post, using new Instagram graph APIs?

Tags: instagram, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using new Instagram Graph APIs for my application, I am interested in knowing if there is any way I can get profile information about the user who comments on my Instagram posts and **what are possible ways to get the direct message exchanging with those users**, as far I found that Instagram Graph APIs do not provide any direct messaging support for now, though I found some private APIs but these are not reliable as they can be restricted any time in future.

**So all I need is to get those user`s information who commented on my Posts** ie- I get only comment_id from the web-hook request from Instagram Graph APIs but when using that comment I try to get its owner/user it does not return any user information except username.
   Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this endpoint:

v3.0/{comment_id}?fields=id,timestamp,username,text